# Configure kendo ui treeview for my json data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have the following data:

```
[
{"id":1,"parendId":0,"name":"Foods","hasItems":"true},  
{"id":2,"parentId":1,"name":"Fruits","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":3,"parentId":1,"name":"Vegetables","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":4,"parentId":2,"name":"apple","hasItems":"false"},  
{"id":5,"parentId":2,"name":"orange","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":6,"parentId":3,"name":"tomato","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":7,"parentId":3,"name":"carrot","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":8,"parentId":3,"name":"cabbage","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":9,"parentId":3,"name":"potato","hasItems":"true"},  
{"id":10,"parentId":3,"name":"lettuce","hasItems":"false"}
]
```

Can someone tell how I can configure kendo ui treeview for the above data?
Also, is it possible to have this treeview inside kendo ui dropdownlist?

**Update:**

This is what I have so far...

```
categories = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: UrlThatFetchesData
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            parentId: 'parentId',
            name: 'name'
        }
    }
});

$('#tvCategories').kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: categories,
    dataTextField: 'name',
    dataValueField: 'id'
});
```

All items are displayed as main category, one right below the other.
How do I get the the treeview to use the parentId?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to embed inside the treeview item those other data? If that is so, your KendoTreeview should look like this:

```
@(  Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                            .Name("Treeview")
                            .DataTextField("name") //display text
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Read(read => read
                                .Action("ActionThatFetchesData", "ControllerName")
                                )
                            )
                            .TemplateId("treeview-template") //name of the template
                            )
```

And then use a Kendo Template that will display the json

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
     <span>#:  item.id#</span>
     <span>#:  item.parentId#</span>
     <span>#:  item.name#</span>
     <span>#:  item.hasItems#</span>
</script>
```

Comment: Jude, thanks for the help. I am not using MVC. Please see my update. Can you help me with my setup?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer, @TimothyLeeRussell did you figure it out, if so, could you please share?

Comment: @Jain I decided to go a different way and now I am using the Angular directives for working with the Kendo TreeView.